# React Native - Unable to get TabNavigator to Work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I installed react-navigation and got a Switch Navigator to work, but I am unable to get a Tab Navigator to work. When I compile, I get this error:

> Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React
>   classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending
>   requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.

Then when I dismiss the error, I get a blank screen. My compiler doesn't detect any syntax errors.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { MainFeed, Login, Camera, Profile } from "./components/screens";
import { SwitchNavigator, TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    feed: MainFeed,
    camera: Camera,
    profile: Profile


});

const MainStack  = SwitchNavigator({
    login: Login,
    main: Tabs
});

class InstaClone extends Component {
    render(){

        return <MainStack/>;

    }
}

export default InstaClone;
```

Comment: just for your info, their API changed a bit since version2. [bottom tab](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html) and [top tab](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html). Here is an example of me using [stack navigator](https://github.com/pkcwong/react-native-meteor-starter/blob/master/src/screens/navigator.js)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it to work.